# Center Highstock chart scrollbar handle

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a bunch of stock charts rendered with Highstock charting API.

In an attempt to center the scrollbar handle for each chart, I use the following piece of code:

```
            /* ============ Position chart scroll BEGIN ============  */

            $(".highcharts-container").each(function () {
              var scrollBar = $(this).find('.highcharts-scrollbar');
              var scrollBarElms = scrollBar.find('rect');
              var scrollBarTrackWidth = $(scrollBarElms[0]).attr("width");
              var scrollBarHandleWidth = $(scrollBarElms[1]).attr("width");
              var xPos = (scrollBarTrackWidth / 2) - (scrollBarHandleWidth / 2);
              $(scrollBarElms[1]).attr("x", xPos);
            });

            /*  ============ Position chart scroll END ============ */
```

The problem is that the handle and the 3 vertical lines that should 'decorate' it are separated. (You can see the entire thing [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vz17omm5/10/).)

Any suggestions on how to keep them together?

Comment: Which vertical lines? Anyway, why do you use some jQuery method to move HTML tags in the DOM, instead of using `chart.xAxis.min`/`max`?

Comment: I need to place that hendle in the middle. Min/max only puts it to extremes. Right?

Comment: When setting min and max for xAxis, you will set that for navigator too, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/enj83a6L/ - of course it may a bit vary, if you are using ordinal axis with huge gaps.

Comment: In my case, the number of points is variable, the series is dynamically generated, so the above solution, even though elegant, does not apply.

Comment: Which part is wrong in your opinion? `range=50` ? It's just number of points for the selected range. You want this make more dynamic? Instead of `50` set there `l * 0.1` and you will choose then 10% of all points to be inside the selected area.. I think my solution applies perfectly for your case, however may require some polishing, to fit your needs. And if series is dynamically generated, then after adding that series you can still set required extremes (using `setExtremes()` method).

Comment: Sure, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/vz17omm5/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function getData() {
        // generate an array of random data
        var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

        for (i = -999; i <= 0; i = i + 1) {
            data.push([
            time + i * 1000,
            Math.round(Math.random() * 100)]);
        }
        return data;
    }

    function getRange(data) {
        var l = data.length,
            range = l * 0.1, // number of points -> 10%
            min = data[Math.round(l / 2 - range / 2)][0],
            max = data[Math.round(l / 2 + range / 2)][0];

        return {
            min: min,
            max: max
        };
    }

    /* ============ CHARTS OPTIONS BEGIN ============ */

      var options = {
          chart: {
              zoomType: 'x',
          events: {
            load: function () {
                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime();
                    var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y]);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
      },
      xAxis: {

      },
      rangeSelector: {
          buttons: [{
              count: 1,
              type: 'minute',
              text: '1M'
      }, {
          count: 5,
          type: 'minute',
          text: '5M'
      }, {
          type: 'all',
          text: 'All'
      }],
      inputEnabled: false,
      selected: 0
      },
      title: {
          text: null
      },
      exporting: {
          enabled: false
      },
      // Disable navigator
      navigator: {
          enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
          name: ''
      }]
  }

  /* ============ CHARTS OPTIONS END ============ */

  /* ============ DRAW CHARTS BEGIN ============ */

  function renderCharts() {
      $('div.chart-container').each(function () {
          var chartId = $(this).attr('id');
          var chartIdParts = chartId.split('-');
          var chartIdentifier = chartIdParts[1];

          //Set chart options dinamically
          var chartId = "chart" + chartIdentifier;
          var chart = $('#' + chartId);
          var renderTo = "chartcontainer-" + chartIdentifier;

          //Render Charts for each aech container
          options.chart.renderTo = renderTo;
          options.chart.type = 'line';
          options.series[0].data = getData();
          var range = getRange(options.series[0].data);
          options.xAxis.min = range.min;
          options.xAxis.max = range.max;
          var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart($.extend(true, {}, options));
      });
  }

  function setChatType() {
      // Show types list (piker)
      $('.current-type').on('click', function () {
          $(this).parents('div.chart-options').find('ul.type ul').addClass('clicked');
      });

      $('.chart-options ul ul li a').on('click', function () {

          //Get piked chart type
          var type = $(this).parent('li').attr('data-chart-type');

          // For text and Title Capitalization
          var textAndTitle = type.replace(/^[a-z]/, function (m) {
              return m.toUpperCase()
          });

          // Show piked type in picker
          var currSetClass = 'current-type ' + type;
          $(this).parents('.chart-options').find('.current-type')
              .text(textAndTitle)
              .attr({
              class: currSetClass,
              title: textAndTitle
          });

          // Then Hide the types list
          $('.chart-options ul ul').removeClass('clicked');

          //Identify current chart container by ID
          var chartCtnId = $(this).parents('div.chart').find('.chart-container').attr('id');

          // Render chart again with new type
          options.chart.renderTo = chartCtnId;
          options.chart.type = type;
          var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart($.extend(true, {}, options));

      });
    }

  /* ============ DRAW CHARTS END ============ */

  $(document).ready(function () {

      $("article.grid:even").addClass('left')
      $("article.grid:odd").addClass('right');

      // Draw charts
      renderCharts();

      // Set/change chart type
      setChatType();

  });
```

The entire solution can be found [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vz17omm5/12/).
Thanks to Paweł Fus for help!